# How to define extended interface type in TypeScript to avoid 'does not exist in type' error?

Tags: typescript, interface

I need to define a TypeScript Interface called: ApplicationSubSectionIntegrations which is a mock data from backend like this:

```
{data : [
      {
        "@id": "e6a99ed0-b7be-4f57-866b-58da27e5090d",
        "formSubSectionId": 10359,
        "formSubSectionDisplayName": "Clinical & Work Experiences",
        "actions": [
          {
            "@id": "760e9408-29b1-41b5-a823-f3217b08bee2",
            "id": 315,
            "name": "Complete Tile",
            "description": "This will complete the Time2Track subsection when the integration notification is sent",
            "standardName": "CompleteTile",
            "tableName": "INTEGRATION_ACTION",
            "createdDate": "2020-04-16 15:40:51",
            "updatedDate": "2020-04-16 15:40:53",
            "customBlocksAllowed": false,
            "standardSubsectionBlocksAllowed": false,
            "standardSubSectionTypesAllowed": false,
            "webAdmitName": null,
            "required": false,
            "enabled": false,
            "catalogueModels": [],
            "parentCatalogueEntityId": '314',
            "inUse": false
          }
        ],
        "dataSources": [
          {
            "@id": "ccf7625c-b0a5-446a-b8ad-4d06daa4115f",
            "id": 317,
            "name": "Time2Track-SummaryOfPracticumExperiences",
            "description": "Time2Tracks datasource for tile completion",
            "standardName": "Time2Track-SummaryOfPracticumExperiences",
            "tableName": "INTEGRATION_DATASOURCE",
            "createdDate": "2020-04-16 15:44:17",
            "updatedDate": "2020-04-16 15:44:19",
            "customBlocksAllowed": false,
            "standardSubsectionBlocksAllowed": false,
            "standardSubSectionTypesAllowed": false,
            "webAdmitName": null,
            "required": false,
            "enabled": false,
            "catalogueModels": [],
            "parentCatalogueEntityId": '314',
            "inUse": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
};
```

I implemented in this way:

```
import { CatalogueEntity } from './catalogue-entity.model';


interface ActionItem extends CatalogueEntity {
    ['@id']?: string;
    customBlocksAllowed: boolean;
    standardSubsectionBlocksAllowed: boolean;
    standardSubSectionTypesAllowed: boolean;
    webAdmitName?: string;
    required: boolean;
    inUse: boolean;
}

interface ApplicationSubSectionIntegrationItem {
    ['@id']?: string;
    formSubSectionId: number;
    formSubSectionDisplayName: string;
    actions: ActionItem[];
    dataSources: ActionItem[];
}

export interface ApplicationSubSectionIntegrations {
   data: Array<ApplicationSubSectionIntegrationItem>;
}
```

catalogue-entity.model.ts:

```
import { CatalogueModel } from './catalogue-model.model';

export interface CatalogueEntity {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  standardName: string;
  tableName: string;
  catalogueModels: CatalogueModel[];
  enabled: boolean;
  createdDate: string;
  updatedDate: string;
  parentCatalogueEntityId?: string;
}
```

catalogue-model.model.ts:

```
export interface CatalogueModel {
  ['@id']?: string;
  id?: number;
  name?: string;
  value?: any;
  description: null;
  standardName?: string;
  type?: string;
  catalogueEntity?: string;
  createdDate?: string;
  updatedDate?: string;
  enabled?: boolean;
}
```

However, when I assigned this to a varabile like this, it gives me such error:

```
 applicationSubSectionIntegrationList: ApplicationSubSectionIntegrations[];
 this.applicationSubSectionIntegrationList = {data : [...]}
```

Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'data' does not exist in type 'ApplicationSubSectionIntegrations[]'.ts(2322)

Does anyone know how to implement this interface correctly? Appreciated in advance!

Comment: The last two lines say that `applicationSubSectionIntegrationList` is an array, but you are then assigning an object with a `data` property instead.  Have you tried just `this.applicationSubSectionIntegrationList = [...]` directly?  Note that a [mcve] which can be dropped into a standalone IDE to demonstrate your issue would be helpful.  Right now you've included a large amount of interface definitions but the actual code where you have your error is missing and you're only showing pseudocode there.  Most of the code in this question is not relevant to the error.

Comment: @jcalz, thank you for your hint. Will try this.